# Search in Meteor with pagination

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor website where I can sort by latest and greatest posts.
I'm also doing a search but I get to spend the input text to the controller to search every time you make a keyup .
However , I can do it (though not dynamic) to another button, such as button "Search" seeking post with text 'eteor' (though not paginated ).

I have this event for the input:

```
    Template.header.events({
        'keyup input': function(e) {
           // I want this on OTHER controller (no in HeaderController) --> $(e.target).context.value
           // for do this --> Collection.find({postId: 'inputText'});
        }
    });
```

Do you know a certain package or a way to pass this data event to other view controller?

I try to imitate the search engine would be this:
https://atmospherejs.com/?q=

My website:
http://xiwi.meteor.com/

Comment: Please be more specific, show us the code you are trying to implement it with.

Comment: I edited post with code